# Angular: Weird behavior of [style.display] in IE 11 - Two way binding not working

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7

Hi i am developing a web application and the target browser is IE-11 and above. I am using [style.display] to hide or show an element in one of my component. The code is as follows

```
    <cm-configure-add-cart class="configure" 
                       [style.display]="(configWorkflowComp.visible == false) ? 'none' : 'initial' ">
    </cm-configure-add-cart>
```

This seems to be not working. When i inspect the dev tools i see style="display: none" even though the value of `configWorkflowComp.visible is true`

[image]

But if i change the code to (from display to opacity)

```
<cm-configure-add-cart class="configure" 
                   [style.opacity]="(configWorkflowComp.visible == false) ? 0 : 1 ">
</cm-configure-add-cart>
```

Everything seems working fine and the element displays.

[image]

Why is this happening. Does angular two way binding doesnt work with [style.display] or am i missing something here?. Please help i am stuck.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried ngStyle as follows

```
[ngStyle]="{'display': configWorkflowComp.visible === false ? 'none' : 'initial'}"
```

This did not work either.

**I have tried with class based approach which works fine. But my question here is , why is [style.display] is not working !?**

Comment: maybe not related but you may want to actually remove parts of template from DOM with ngIf that should remove some unnecessary updates of template that shouldnt be visible

Comment: @Xesenix  i want to keep the elements in dom as i have viewchild reference to those elements.

Comment: Instead of `[style.display]`, you can simply use `[hidden]="condition"`

Comment: I already have solution using the class or by using hidden. But my question is why [style.display], is not working

Comment: after testing it looks its not only IE issue display dosn't update on any browser

Comment: @Xesenix for me it seems like working fine on chrome

Comment: ok i had error in my test

Comment: Ok i managed to correctly test it this time check this on IE https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eg1my7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts should work in all cases it has problems if i use `initial` value instead of `block` or just empty display works also correctly

Comment: Hmm turns out initial property is not supported in ie. Changing it to block fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out initial property is not supported in IE. Changing it to block fixed the issue.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Answer (score 0):

Try with this approach,

Have a class, `.d-none { display: none}`

Add your style with the below format,

`<cm-configure-add-cart class="configure" [ngClass]="{'d-none': !configWorkflowComp.visible}">
 </cm-configure-add-cart>`

Comment: Class approach totally works fine. I have already tried it. Why style.display is not working is the confusion i have.